# Class function Loading HTML page with Variables

Tags: php, html, oop, templating

```
Class Html_Pdf_Export {
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
    //alot of data variables

    //How I have it now
    function getHtml()
    {
        $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        1000 lines of code with data variables
        </html>";

        $this->html = $html;
        return $this->html;
    }

    function convertToPdf()
    {
         //function that converts $this->html to Pdf
    }

    //How I want the function to be but How do I pass all the data variables?
    function loadHtml()
    {
         $html_load_template = new Html_Load_Template('the_template_i_want_to_load_with_data_variables');
         $this->html = $html_load_template;
         return $this->html;
    }
}
```

I have a class that converts Html to PDF.  The html I have in that class is bloated with 1000-1500 lines of html code that eventually converts to a PDF.  To make it less bloated, I decided to separate the all html to another Classs called Html_Load_Template.  How do I pass all the data variables that Html_Pdf_Export has to the Class Html_Load_Template?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood you correctly you just need to shift getHtml() function to Html_Load_Template class (manual work). So it would look like:

```
Class Html_Pdf_Export {
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
    //alot of data variables

    function convertToPdf()
    {
        //function that converts $this->html to Pdf
    }

    //How I want the function to be but How do I pass all the data variables?
    function loadHtml()
    {
         $html_load_template = new Html_Load_Template('the_template_i_want_to_load_with_data_variables');
         $this->html = $html_load_template->getHtml();
         return $this->html;
    }
}
```

and

```
Class Html_Load_Template {
    public function getHtml()
    {
        $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        1000 lines of code with data variables
        </html>";

        $this->html = $html;
        return $this->html;
    }

    // other functions if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how your "Html_Load_Template" Class looks like, but basically I guess you want to outsource the "getHtml" part to a different file, right?

So if you move your code to the Load-Class...

```
function getHtml()
{
    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    1000 lines of code with data variables
    </html>";
    $this->html = $html;
    return $this->html;
}
```

... wouldn't it work if you get the Data via...

```
$this->html = $html_load_template->getHtml();
```

Comment: Oh, AdamM had the same idea. :)